# Correct way to set only circle size in Material UI Stepper?

Tags: material-ui

As you can see in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-noyce-b2dc0?file=/src/myStyles.ts), I have used the 'transform' property, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47790825/8940624), also tried changing the `font-size` on the `StepIconProps` (commented out code on CSB).

The first option results in the circle resizing while still retaining its centre, and hence its alignment with the line, but the text stays in the same place.

The second option means the circle loses its alignment with the line, but the text stays nicely positioned relative to the circle.

I'm not sure either are entirely the correct way to do it. There is an [example in the docs](https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/#customized-stepper) where the icon has been customised, but this involves an implementation a whole new icon, which I'd rather avoid. I am happy with all of the default appearance, with the only exception being the size.

Answer (score 0):

I created a div element using styled components and I passed it as a prop `icon` at `StepLabel` from material UI.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Stepper, Step, StepLabel } from "@material-ui/core";

const stepsOptions = {
  0: [0],
  1: [0, 1],
  2: [0, 1, 2],
};

const StepIcon = styled.div`
  background-color: ${({ backgroundColor }) =>
    backgroundColor ? "#008a98" : "#DCDCDC"};
  color: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  z-index: 1;
`;

const Component = () => {

  const [stepsArray, setStepsArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setStepsArray(stepsOptions[activeStep]);
  }, [activeStep]);
  
  return (
    <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} alternativeLabel>
      {steps.map((label, index) => (
        <Step key={label}>
          <StepLabel
            icon={
              <StepIcon backgroundColor={stepsArray.includes(index)}>
                <p>{index + 1}</p>
              </StepIcon>
            }
          >
            <Paragraph>{label}</Paragraph>
          </StepLabel>
        </Step>
      ))}
    </Stepper>
  )}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).